# Element lost? Call a scientist!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, science, flags, chemistry

I was searching for a specific element, but I couldn't find it. So I called three scientists in different countries in order to find the element.

[image: three flags]

What was the element I was looking for, and where am I able to find it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were looking for

> cadmium

and you finally found it in

> Poland.

After all, when you called the three scientists,

> you first had to use their respective countries' calling codes. Those are the atomic numbers of Po, La, and Nd. So the scientists told you to try calling Poland — and that made you dial the atomic number of cadmium. To actually *get* the cadmium, though, calling was not enough: you had to go pick it up yourself.

Answer (score 17):

I think you're looking for...

> one of:
>  - element 84, **POLONIUM**,
>  - element 96, **CURIUM**, or
>  - element 48, **CADMIUM**
>
>  All of which you might find in **PoLaNd**, depending on how you define your search...

Why the strange capitalisation there? Well, first let's identify the three flags. These are those of:

> Vietnam, Colombia, and Malaysia.

We clearly need to use these identities somehow to produce some recognisable hint to a solution. After fruitlessly considering the country names, their capital cities, and their ISO-2 codes, I finally hit upon...

> ...their **international dialling codes**. These are, respectively, +84, +57, and +60.

Since we are dealing with elements, it's then a natural follow-on thought to...

> ...look up the elements with these atomic numbers in the Periodic Table. These are the elements **Polonium** (Po), **Lanthanum** (La), and **Neodymium** (Nd).
>
>  String these three symbols together to get the word **PoLaNd** - we're clearly on the right track (or this is one heck of a coincidence)! So if we need to look for an element in Poland, there are three choices I can see immediately:
>
>  - the one that's named after the country: **[POLONIUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polonium)** (from Polonia, the Latin for Poland);
>  - the one that's named after a scientist of Polish nationality: **[CURIUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curium)** (named after its Polish discoverer, [Marie Curie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curium), and her husband Pierre); or
>  - the one whose atomic number is 48, which is the dialling code for Poland: **[CADMIUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadmium)**.